# concatenate two variables from 2 different awk commands in a single echo

Tags: shell, unix

```
Job = grep 'Job:' | awk '{ print $3 }'
Status = grep 'Job Status:' | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

Both the variables are printed correctly by using two echo statements.I want a result like **Job name - status** in a single line.I have tried below commands. But its printing only 2nd variable like **- status**

```
echo "$Job - $Status"
echo "${Job} - ${Status}"
echo -e "${Job} - ${Status}"
```

please help!

Comment: Is `Job = grep 'Job:' | awk '{ print $3 }'` a valid shell syntax?

Comment: Neither of your supposed variable assignments are what you think they are. In shell programming, variable assignments must not have spaces on either side of the `=` - e.g. `x=y` but not `x = y`. Your statements as written attempt to run two programs, named `Job` and `Status`, with various arguments... In addition, even if you resolve that, the `grep` invocations don't have anything to read from (no files named), so they'll attempt to read from your standard input, which is likely not what you are attempting...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single awk command:

```
awk '/Job:/ { job = $3 } /Job Status:/ { status = $3 } END { print job " - " status }' file
```

If `Job:` comes before `Job Status`:

```
awk '/Job:/ { job = $3 } /Job Status:/ { print job " - " $3; exit }' file
```

Or vice versa:

```
awk '/Job Status:/ { status = $3 } /Job Status:/ { print $3 " - " status; exit }' file
```

Comment: Ah, so my solution is independent of the order ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think that should work:

```
echo  $(awk ' /Job:/ { print $3} ' file)" - "$(awk ' /Job Status:/ { print $3} ' file)
```

but konsolebox's version is probably better, as there is only one awk invocation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to find out how to get the result of running some command and store it in a variable. Then you want to do that twice and print both variables on the same line.

So the basic syntax is:

```
result=$(some command)
```

e.g. if

```
date +'%Y'
```

tells you the year is 2014, but you want 2014 in a variable called `year`, you can do

```
year=$(date +'%Y')
```

then you can echo `$year` like this:

```
echo $year
2014
```

So, coming to your actual question, you want two variables, one for the output of each of two commands:

```
job=$(grep "Job:" someFile | awk '{print $3}')
status=$(grep "Job Status:" someFile | awk '{print $3}')
```

then you can do:

```
echo $job $status
```

and get both things on the same line.

The other answers are saying you can avoid invoking `awk` twice, which is true, but doesn't explain how to capture the result of running a command into a variable. In general, you don't need to use `awk` and `grep`, because this:

```
grep xyz | awk ...
```

is equivalent to

```
awk '/xyz/ {...}'
```

but uses one fewer processes (i.e. no `grep`) and therefore fewer resources.

And by the way, you must not put any spaces either side of `=` in bash either. It is

```
variable=something
```

not

```
variable = something
```